# Just a little adventure in cylindrical crosswordland

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]
[Grid in plaintext](https://pastebin.com/webFY4Xr)

This is a cylindrical cryptic crossword. Some "across" clues go beyond the right-hand edge of the grid and continue from the left-hand side. The black part between the two vertical bars is the actual grid; a few columns on both sides have been duplicated in gray as visualization aids.

**Across**
1. Pssht, precipitation? It's quite rare in this place (7)
5. Societal group I call mostly traditional (9)
10. Guidance for arranging trip south (9)
11. Faces of half a dozen wise men (7)
12. Restriction on imports? Abandon ship, get on board another ship (7)
14. Everything I got: a lousy river reptile (9)
15. Tiny sample? China it up! I'll illustrate "writing from the East" (11)
17. Former lover I almost allowed to drive out (5)
18. Health resort in European country (5)
19. Delicate, graciously opening object (5)
20. In philosophy, Dracula is a scary monster (5)
21. Desert's temperature dropped; opinions? (5)
22. Radio host Howard's steely rear (5)
23. Swift strike to capture Palestine's capital (5)

**Down**
1. Entertaining capital of Guinea-Bissau, rats playing instruments (4,7)
2. Reportedly top cause for betrayal (4,7)
3. People from the south violently assault Iran (11)
4. Finally, clean air comes down to low-lying kingdom (11)
5. 7 down's experiment subject: 100 anarchist extremists (3)
6. Rack up, snooker league player – finals taking place near Iowa (5)
7. Prize-winning Austrian vocalist's captivating broken chord (11)
8. Adam's son is smart, getting competent, showing command at sea (11)
9. In the 50s, Adam's wife was in command? That's sensible (5-6)
13. Easily offended Welshman perhaps forgetting a story (7)
16. Hookup number in university on the rise (5)

Comment: Any recommendations on best/easiest ways to solve/fill on a computer?

Comment: @MrSethward There are three ways that I know of: save the image and fill it in an image editor, copy the plaintext grid from the link and fill it in a text editor, or manually recreate the grid in a program you prefer and fill there. There is no mechanism for filling crossword grids directly on this site, unfortunately.

Comment: I have an excel file pre-prepared, with all the cells set to have the same length and width. However, it's still not optimal, as the filling of black cells is still manual :(

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions. The method of filling out isn't the hardest or most fun part anyway. :)

Comment: Great idea! I now eagerly await a toroidal puzzle.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK A Moebius strip puzzle would be another interesting challenge, where it flips on one side of the wraparound.  Or a Kline Bottle, which flips on both dimensions...  Wait, has anyone ever done a 3D crossword?  Hmm...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman 3D cryptics [definitely exist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/three-dimensional+cryptic-crosswords) :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ended up filling out on a PDF editor this round, not very pretty, apologies.

> [image]

My first finished cryptic, been training a bit on them as I'm living for the first time in the UK for lockdown ha!

**ACROSS**

*A1. Pssht, precipitation? It's quite rare in this place (7)*

> Bah! Rain!? Not much of that in **BAHRAIN**

*A5. Societal group I call mostly traditional (9)*

> Our societal group, CLASS + most of I CALl gives us **CLASSICAL**, meaning traditional

*A10. Guidance for arranging trip south (9)*

> Rearrange trip south for some guidance or **TUTORSHIP**

*A11. Faces of half a dozen wise men (7)*

> 6 or VI, a half dozen SAGES gives us **VISAGES** meaning faces

*A12. Restriction on imports? Abandon ship, get on board another ship (7)*

> Abandon ark (ship) from EMBark (get on board), and get on another ship, the ARGO, for **EMBARGO**, a restriction on imports

*A14. Everything I got: a lousy river reptile (9)*

> All (everything) + I + GOT A (mixed up) + R for river, which also could be part of the definition of **ALLIGATOR**

*A15. Tiny sample? China it up! I'll illustrate "writing from the East" (11)*

> **LILLIPUTIAN** which is a sample of chiNA IT UP I'LL ILustrate when reversed or writing from the East

*A17. Former lover I almost allowed to drive out (5)*

> Ex + I LEt gives us **EXILE**, meaning to drive out

*A18. Health resort in European country (5)*

> Spa + in gives **SPAIN**

*A19. Delicate, graciously opening object (5)*

> THIN + Graciously gives **THING**

*A20. In philosophy, Dracula is a scary monster (5)*

> In philosopHY, DRAcula, we have **HYDRA**, a scary monster

*A21. Desert's temperature dropped; opinions? (5)*

> Thanks to @hexomino, if we drop Temperature from our opinions, STANDS, we get **SANDS**

*A22. Radio host Howard's steely rear (5)*

> 3def: Howard **STERN**, **STERN** means steely and **STERN** means rear of a boat

*A23. Swift strike to capture Palestine's capital (5)*

> Strike is RAID around P for **RAPID** or swift

**DOWN**

*D1. Entertaining capital of Guinea-Bissau, rats playing instruments (4,7)*

> Mixing around the head of Guinea, plus BISSAU and RATS, we get some nice **BASS GUITARS** to play!

*D2. Reportedly top cause for betrayal (4,7)*

> Thanks to @oAlt, height (top) reason (cause) reportedly sounds like **HIGH TREASON**!

*D3. People from the south violently assault Iran (11)*

> Rearrange assault Iran to get the very southern **AUSTRALIANS**

*D4. Finally, clean air comes down to low-lying kingdom (11)*

> cleaN ETHER LANDS in the **NETHERLANDS**

*D5. 7 down's experiment subject: 100 anarchist extremists (3)*

> C (100) AnarchisT extremists in Schrodinger's **CAT** experiment

*D6. Rack up, snooker league player – finals taking place near Iowa (5)*

> Iowa with two letter code IA, and thanks to @Gareth, last letters or finals of snookeR leaguE playeR taking place near it. All backwards, to give **AIRER**, meaning rack

*D7. Prize-winning Austrian vocalist's captivating broken chord (11)*

> SINGER swallows whole chord rearranged to CHROD to get **SCHRODINGER**, the Austrian physicist who won the 1933 Nobel Prize in Physics!

*D8. Adam's son is smart, getting competent, showing command at sea (11)*

> Adam's son CAIN + 'S (is) + HIP (smart) gets APT, **CAPTAINSHIP**

*D9. In the 50s, Adam's wife was in command? That's sensible (5-6)*

> EVE surrounded by Ls (50s) HEADED, leading us on the way to **LEVEL HEADED**

*D13. Easily offended Welshman perhaps forgetting a story (7)*

> a BRIT forgetting the 'a' (from) TaLE makes **BRITTLE**, easy to offend

*D16. Hookup number in university on the rise (5)*

> NO (number) + IN + University on the rise gives us a **UNION**, which is a hookup

Comment: Nice work! I had something else in mind for 21 across, though.

Comment: Ninjaed, but only because I'm still trying to figure out 21a :-). My guess at the desert isn't quite the same as yours, for what it's worth, but I expect we're both wrong; at any rate, I haven't yet found anything that fits anything. 6d's wordplay is pretty complicated; it's rot13(ynfg yrggref bs "fabbxre yrnthr cynlre", cyhf VN, nyy erirefrq).

Comment: Ah sorry, won't post til I got them all next time, wasn't sure I would be able to do on my own. Thanks for 6d, that's tough, would not have gotten that!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, rot13(FVAnv pryfvHF --> FVAHF? Ohg qbrfa'g ernyyl svg jvgu "Bcvavbaf?" hayrff gung'f fbzr xvaqn zrqvpny cha un.)

Comment: I think 21A is rot13(FNAQF juvpu vf FGNAQF (bcvavbaf) jvgu G (grzcrengher) qebccrq)

Comment: Ah, genius @hexomino!

Comment: For next time, what's the normal etiquette in regards to posting? Solution + wordplay all at once?

Comment: I normally post solution and wordplay explanations together. Don't feel guilty about posting with a couple of clues unexplained; that's perfectly OK. (I don't mind being ninjaed and it's not like I'm hurting for Meaningless Internet Points.) And yes, well spotted @hexomino!

Comment: (To expand on the posting-with-a-bit-unexplained thing: I will always make a good-faith effort to solve everything myself, but once I'm convinced that I'm not going to figure out the last bit in a reasonable time I don't mind posting an answer with a bit missing.)

Comment: I think the explanation for 2-down is rather that rot13("urvtug ernfba" ("gbc" + "pnhfr") vf n ubzbcubar ("ercbegrqyl") bs uvtu gernfba). There are some other things I'd modify as well in the explanations for 8-down, 13-down, and 16-down, which I will comment later.

Comment: Aaaah I see, yes, correct. Not too good at identifying those homophone indicators.

Comment: Rot13(Sbe 8-qbja, "vf" pna or nooerivngrq gb "'f". "Uvc" vf n flabalz bs "fzneg" (gubhtu V zlfrys unir arire xabja gung orsber), fb F+UVC. Sbe 13-npebff, "sbetrggvat n" vf yvgrenyyl qebccvat gur yrggre N sebz OEVG+GNYR. Sbe 16-qbja, "ubbxhc" pna or "havba" (nabgure guvat V qvq abg xabj nobhg). Abj, "ahzore" pna or nooerivngrq gb "ab.", "va" vf nf vf, naq V guvax "havirefvgl" pna or nooerivngrq gb H. "Ba gur evfr" vf n erirefny vaqvpngbe sbe qbja pyhrf, fb vafgrnq bs AB+VA+H lbh erirefr vg naq trg H+AV+BA.) @jafe can you confirm the explanation for the last? I'm not yet confident about it.

Comment: There may have been opportunities for improvement in other clue explanations as well, but I'm leaving that to other people; I'm catching up on anime :P (I can comment once more later afterward, though.)

Comment: @oAlt Yeah, those are exactly as intended.

Comment: Am back. A15 and A19 seem to be the ones you are unsure of (and it is also not yet clear to me what the wordplay for A19 is.) But, for A15, rot13("Fnzcyr" pna zrna gung gur jbeq vf uvqqra fbzrjurer va gur erfg bs gur pyhr'f jbeqf (whfg yvxr N20). Ubjrire, gurer vf n gjvfg, nf "jevgvat sebz gur Rnfg" -> "jevgvat sebz gur rnfg" -> jevgvat onpxjneq, be gung gur uvqqra jbeq vf *va erirefr.* Vaqrrq, lbh jvyy frr gung "Puvan vg hc! V'yy vyyhfgengr" unf YVYYVCHGVNA ohg erirefrq: "puvAN VG HC VYY VYyhfgengr".)

Comment: Great puzzle @jafe! And excellent solution! I think 5-down might be better explained as rot13(P (100) + (N)anepuvf(G) (gur rkgerzvfgf bs "nanepuvfg")).

Comment: @oAlt: I think A19 is rot13(GUVA (qryvpngr) + (T)enpvbhfyl (bcravat bs tenpvbhfyl).

Comment: @JeremyDover oh... makes sense :P